# Android: how to add UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS

Tags: android, root

I have a question, I need in my AndroidManifest.xml this premission - `UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS`, but when I put it there, I get an error - `Permission is only granted to system apps`
so how I can solve this error?

Comment: As a general rule, any permissions described as "Not for use by third-party applications" is not for use by third party applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own custom version of Android, compile it into a ROM mod, and sign your app with the same signing key as you signed the ROM mod.

Or, root your device and install your app on the system partition.